# AWS ECS repository creation with EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

Hello,

I have a running EC2 with applications installed and I want to migrate the app onto Docker container.So, can we create an ECS Docker repository using running EC2 instance?

Answer (score 0):

The biggest thing in your question is dockerizing your apps.The complexity varies as per technologies used in app, app server as docker image and many other things comes into picture.Its not direct conversion and you need to do lot of work to convert apps as docker images depends app comlexity.

ECR is docker registry where you store docker images and you don't need ec2 instance for that.

Once you docker images and ECR, you need to create ECS cluster to run your apps docker containers.